# Show that, $(s+1)\gamma-\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{s}x^ndx=\sum_{i=1}^{s}H_i-\ln(s+1)!$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

**harmonic numbers**
$H_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$

**Euler's constant**

$\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty} [H_n-\ln(n)]$

**Factorial**

$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots2\cdot1$; valid for all non-negative integers

Show that,

$$(s+1)\gamma-\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\sum_{n=0}^{s}x^ndx=\sum_{i=1}^{s}H_i-\ln(s+1)!$$

---

Inspiring from the integral of Euler's constant; see Wikipedia
$$\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\gamma$$
**Mathematical experimental**

We did trial and error using wolfram integrator and observe the numerical values of the integral and we was able to come up with a closed form for it.

**Unfortunately we are unable to provide a proof for it, can anyone provide us a prove of it?**

Comment: By chance, are you and pisquare the same person?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  That is very likely, as they format their questions the same way, and both use the odd phrase "mathematical experimental".

Comment: @nospoon when your eye is open contact me, we talk. I was talking to jack last night and I haven't done with him yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to check that:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)x^k}\,dx &=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t e^t}\right)e^{-kt}\,dt \tag{1}\\[0.2cm]&=&\gamma+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-kt}-1}{e^t-1}\,dt-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-kt}-1}{te^t}\,dt\tag{2}\\[0.2cm]&=&\color{blue}{\gamma-H_k+\log(k+1)}\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*} $$
then sum over $k$. Explanation:

- $(1)$ : substitution $x=e^{-t}$;
- $(2)$ : we exploit $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{te^t}\right)\,dt=\gamma$ and break the remaining integral in two parts;
- $(3)$ : the first integral can be computed by just expanding the integrand function as a geometric sum and exploiting $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-nt}\,dt=\frac{1}{n}$; the second integral can be computed from [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Comment: Are you trying to be banned at all costs? I can give you a hand.

Comment: The comments in all this post (1779314) are just so weird - weirdest post on the site! Good answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two pence worth and is not a complete answer but paves the way I think.

**Theorem [Euler 1731]**
The limit
$$\gamma = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(H_n-\log n)$$
Is given by the convergent series
$$\gamma = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\zeta(n)}{n}$$

We can evaluate this formula using Mercator's expansion
$$\log(1+x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$
and in doing so we find
\begin{align}
\log 2 &= 1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)^{3}-\ldots\\
\log \frac{3}{2} &= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}-\ldots\\
\log \frac{4}{3} &= \frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3}-\ldots\\
\log \frac{5}{4} &= \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{3}-\ldots\\
\end{align}
summing columns of the first $n$ terms gives
$$\log(n+1) = H_n-\frac{1}{2}H_{n, 2}+\frac{1}{3}H_{n, 3}-\ldots$$
or
$$H_n-\log(n+1) = \frac{1}{2}H_{n, 2}-\frac{1}{3}H_{n, 3}+\ldots$$

Comment: And so? Apparently, this has nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio And, so?

Comment: So this is not an answer.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio From my definition of 'answer' I direct you tot he answers of this thread http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11723/are-answers-that-have-no-explanations-useful?lq=1